# FLUTTER: How to stack images for voting app

Tags: flutter, vote

I am doing a voting app and I have a problem, I want to stack images as many time there is votes(1 stack per vote). This is a picture of what I want to do. I tried to use Listview like this

```dart
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/results/green.png'),
    ),
    Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/results/green.png'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The problem is that there is so much space between the 2 images.
Can you help me ?

[image]

Comment: check `ListView` widget

Comment: Hello,

What did you try so far?

Comment: I update the post, you can see what I tried :)

Comment: what space? between the items? i dont see any...

Comment: Yes there is space between items, idk why

Comment: There's no space between the images. It only looks like there is because of the forced perspective illusion created by the difference between the green and white sections of the image. What you want instead is for the images to _overlap a bit_.

Comment: Easiest way to do this would be with two images: one that is clipped at the top for being a chip that another chip is above, and one to use for the topmost chip.

Comment: The image in the post is what I want to do ! I didn't do that !

Comment: Sorry Abion47 I didn't understand :/

Comment: It's nice to know what you want it to do, but it's hard to help if we don't know what it's currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the image with:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  heightFactor: 0.94/*change this value until you are satisfied (between 0 and 1)*/,
  child: //your image
),
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! Do you know how can I have one child per vote ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean can you describe it a little more please?

Comment: On the screen there are 6 "green plates", it is for 6 votes. I want to pass a number as argument and it will display the number of image I passed.
Example: There is 5 vote so I want to add 5 images in Listview

Comment: @LucaMathevet use `ListView.builder`

Comment: just use this:

ListView.builder(
   itemCount: /*put the number of items here*/,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
      return: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
       heightFactor: 0.94/*change this value until you are satisfied (between 0 and 1)*/,
        child: //your image
);
   }
)